A 4d integral, Exercise I-8 p.68-69 from "Mathematics for the physical sciences" (Dover), Laurent Schwartz
The first part is about two versions of a formula by Feynman for the inverse of a product, one of which being
$$ \frac{1}{a_1\, a_2 \, \cdots\, a_n} = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_1} \cdots \int_0^{1-x_1 -x_2 -\,  \cdots -x_{n-2}} \frac{(n-1)!\, dx_1\, dx_2\, \cdots\, dx_{n-1}}{\big[x_1(a_1 -a_n) + x_2 (a_2 - a_n ) + \cdots + x_{n-1}(a_{n-1} - a_n) + a_n \big]^n}\\
$$
This is applied to compute an integral: (partially following the notations of the book)
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} \frac{(A\cdot K)\big[\, C\cdot (K + V) \big]}{K^2 (K^2 + 2\, K\cdot V) (K^2 + 2\, K\cdot W)} d^4 K \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where all capital letters are elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$, $\; \cdot\ $ denotes the scalar product and $K^2 = K\cdot K$. The vectors are such that
$$ \left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
A\cdot V &= A\cdot W\\ C\cdot V &= C\cdot W\\ V^2 &= W^2 \\ A\cdot C &=0
\end{aligned}\right. \tag{2} \label{2}$$
Following the instructions, one obtains
$$\begin{split}
\frac{1}{K^2 (K^2 + 2\, K\cdot V) (K^2 + 2\, K\cdot W)} &= \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_1} \frac{2! \, dx_1 \, dx_2}{\big[x_1 (-2\, K\cdot W) + 2\,x_2\, K\cdot (V-W) + (K^2 + 2\, K\cdot W) \big]^3}\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_1} \frac{2\, dx_1 \, dx_2}{\big[ K^2 + 2\, K\cdot \big((1-x_1 -x_2) W \,+ x_2\, V \big) \big]^3}
\end{split}$$
One should then first integrate w.r.t. $K$ and perform a 4-d "spherical coordinate" change of variables. Here, if one does not consider the numerator, then integral will diverge (at least if I didn't make any mistake).
(It seems to me that one can also obtain a (probably divergent) expression by first integrating w.r.t. the $x_i$... I didn't carry the computation to its term.)
But in order to take the numerator into account one must wisely choose the basis for the definition of the angles...
One can evacuate the case $V=W=0$, which seems to vanish if one integrates on the angles first and then on $K$. Let us now directly look at the case $V\neq W \neq 0$. Three orthoGOnal vectors are given by $(A,C,V-W)$. This is enough to define the 4-d angles. Using again the notations similar to that of the exercise:
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
K_4 &= K\, \cos(a_1)\\ K_3 &= K\, \sin(a_1)\, \cos(a_2) \\ K_2 & = K\, \sin(a_1)\, \sin(a_2)\, \sin(a_3)\\ K_1 & = K\, \sin(a_1)\, \sin(a_2)\, \cos(a_3)
\end{aligned}
\right. \tag{3}\label{3}$$
where now $K:=\lVert\vec{K}\rVert$ is a radius, $\ a_1$ the angle between $\vec{K}$ and $\vec{A}$, $\ a_2$ that between the projection of $\vec{K}$ on the hyperplane $\vec{A}^{\perp}$ and $\vec{C}$, and finally $\ a_3$ that between the projection of $\vec{K}$ on the codimension 2 space $\mathrm{Span}(\vec{A},\vec{C})^{\perp}$ and $\vec{V}-\vec{W}$. With this choice
$$\frac{(A\cdot K)\big[\, C\cdot (K + V) \big]}{K^2 (K^2 + 2\, K\cdot V) (K^2 + 2\, K\cdot W)}=\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_1} \frac{2\, (AK\cos(a_1))\big(C(K\sin(a_1)\cos(a_2)+ \vec{C}\cdot \vec{V}\big) dx_1 \, dx_2}{\big[ K^2 + 2\, \vec{K}\cdot \big((1-x_1 -x_2) \vec{W} \,+ x_2\, \vec{V} \big) \big]^3} $$
where the r.h.s. $A,K,C$ denote the norm of the corresponding vectors.
Let us detail the denominator, using the fact that $V_4 = W_4$ and $V_3 =W_3$:
$$\begin{aligned}
K^2 + 2\, K\cdot \big((1-x_1 -x_2) W \,+ x_2\, V \big) &= K^2 + 2\, K\big((1-x_1) \cos(a_1) W_4 + (1-x_1) \sin(a_1) \cos(a_2) W_3 \big)\\
& + 2\, K\big((1-x_1 - x_2) W_2 + x_2 \, V_2\big)\sin(a_1)\, \sin(a_2)\, \sin(a_3)\\
& +  2\, K\big((1-x_1 - x_2) W_1 + x_2 \, V_1\big) \sin(a_1)\, \sin(a_2)\, \cos(a_3) 
\end{aligned}$$
Because the "local" basis "corresponding" to the spherical coordinates is orthogonal, one has
$$ d^4 \vec{K} = dK \times K \, da_1 \times K\, \sin(a_1)\, da_2 \times K\, \sin(a_1)\, \sin(a_2)\, da_3 = K^3\, \sin^2(a_1)\, \sin(a_2)\, dK\, da_1\, da_2\, da_3$$
One must now show that the denominator does not vanish while the numerator does not, in a way that makes the integral diverge... This seems much too tedious for an exercise, I suspect I'm missing something.
I have also considered the alternative to take
$$ Z:= (1-x_1 - x_2) W + x_2\, V = (1-x_1) W + x_2\, (V-W)\ \in \mathbb{R}^4 $$
as the "reference" axis to define the angle $a_1$ (in analogy to the $Z$-axis, w.r.t. which one defines the usual $\theta$ angle). At least, there will fewer $\cos(a_i),\, \sin(a_i)$ factors in the denominator, which is much easier to integrate.


Last attempt that has the same divergence, as in the case of a numerator equal to 1: one can rewrite the denominator using:
$$ K^2 +2\, K\cdot Z = (K+Z)^2 - Z^2$$
Hence one obtains with the change of variable $\tilde{K} = K+ Z$, of jacobian determinant 1
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} \frac{2\, (A\cdot K)\big[\, C\cdot (K + V) \big]}{\big[ K^2 +2\, K\cdot Z\big]^3} d^4 K = \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} \frac{2\, A\cdot \big(\tilde{K} - (1-x_1)W - x_2\, (V-W)\big)\times C\cdot \big(\tilde{K} +x_1\, W + (1-x_2)\, (V-W)\big)}{\left[ \tilde{K}^2 - Z^2 \right]^3} d^4 \tilde{K} $$
Performing the 4d spherical change of variables, one obtains $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} \cdots d^4 K$
$$ \begin{split}
& = \int \frac{2\, \big[ AK\cos(a_1) +(x_1 -1) \,\vec{A}\cdot \vec{W}\big]\big[CK\sin(a_1)\cos(a_2)+ x_1\, \vec{C}\cdot \vec{W}\big]\, K^3\, \sin^2(a_1)\, \sin(a_2)\, dK\, da_1\, da_2\, da_3}{\left[ K^2 - Z^2 \right]^3}\\
&= 2\cdot 2 \pi  \int \frac{\big[ AK\cos(a_1) +(x_1 -1) \,\vec{A}\cdot \vec{W}\big]\big[CK\sin(a_1)\cos(a_2)+ x_1\, \vec{C}\cdot \vec{W}\big]\, K^3\, \sin^2(a_1)\, \sin(a_2)\, dK\, da_1\, da_2}{\left[ K^2 - Z^2 \right]^3}
\end{split}$$
For the integration w.r.t. $a_2$ from $0$ to $\pi$, there is a first term $\propto \cos(a_2)\, \sin(a_2) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d a_2}\sin^2(a_2)$, whose integral vanishes and a second term which is only proportional to $\sin(a_2)$, whose integral is $2$. Hence
$$\cdots = 8 \pi  \int \frac{\big[ AK\cos(a_1) +(x_1 -1) \,\vec{A}\cdot \vec{W}\big]\, x_1\, (\vec{C}\cdot \vec{W})\, K^3\, \sin^2(a_1)\, dK\, da_1}{\left[ K^2 - Z^2 \right]^3}$$
Once again, for the integration w.r.t. $a_1$, there is a first term proportional to $\cos(a_1)\, \sin^2(a_2) = - \frac{1}{3} \frac{d}{d a_1} \sin^3(a_1)$ which vanishes, leaving us with
$$\begin{split}
\cdots &= 8 \pi  \int_0^{+\infty} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{x_1\,(x_1 -1) \,(\vec{A}\cdot \vec{W})\, (\vec{C}\cdot \vec{W})\, K^3\, \sin^2(a_1)}{\left[ K^2 - Z^2 \right]^3}\, da_1 \, dK\\
&=  8 \pi  \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x_1\,(x_1 -1) \,(\vec{A}\cdot \vec{W})\, (\vec{C}\cdot \vec{W})\, K^3}{\left[ K^2 - Z^2 \right]^3} \, dK \cdot \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1 - \cos(2a_1)}{2}\, da_1\\
&= 4 \pi^2  \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x_1\,(x_1 -1) \,(\vec{A}\cdot \vec{W})\, (\vec{C}\cdot \vec{W})\, K^3}{\left[ K^2 - Z^2 \right]^3} \, dK 
\end{split}$$
This diverges...

A minor variation in the use of Feynman's equation is to take $a_3=K^2$. This has the advantage that the expression in the denominator is $$2x_1(K\cdot V)+2x_2 (K\cdot W)+K^2.$$ This renders the substitution $S=K+x_1 V+x_2 W$ more transparent.

One idea here is to blithely integrate with respect to $K$ at the end, since the issues only occur at $K\approx |Z|$ rather than the endpoints. But that seems wholly out of step with the rest of Schwartz, which otherwise takes issues of convergence seriously. (It doesn't even exist in the sense of a principal value integral...)

Up to mistakes (which i often make), the question may in fact be, are there $A, C, V, W$ such that the integral converges...


the conditions on $A,C,V,W$ imply that they form an orthogonal basis of the Euclidean space $R^4.$

The integral does not seem to be  absolutely convergent since $dK=r^3dr d\theta$ in polar coordinates, where $r=\|K\|$ and $d\theta$ is the uniform measure on the sphere $S^3$ suitably normalised: it makes the function asymptotic to $1/r$

Writing $K=x_1A+x_2C+x_3V+x_4W$ then as a function of $x_1$ the function to be integrated is odd and its integral is $0.$

the complicated Feynman formula is a particular case of the following Dirichlet integral. If $b_1,\ldots,b_n>0$ the Dirichlet distribution $D(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ of $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is concentrated on the tetrahedron $X_i>0$, $X_1+\cdots+X_n=1$ such that the law of $((X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}))$ is $$Cx_1^{b_1-1}\ldots x_{n-1}^{b_1-1}(1-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1})^{b_n-1}dx_1\ldots dx_{n-1}$$ where $C=\Gamma(b)/(\Gamma(b_1)\ldots \Gamma(b_n))$ with $b=b_1+\cdots+b_n.$ The Feynman formula is the particular case of$$E\left(\frac{1}{(a_1X_1+\cdots+a_nX_n)^b}\right)=\frac{1}{a_1^{b_1}\ldots a_n^{b_n}}$$ when $b_1=\ldots=b_n=1.$


I am aware of these remarks will not help for the bushy method suggest by Schwartz.

I don't agree that $A,C,V,W$ constitute an orthogonal basis. Consider $A=(1,0,0,0), C=(0,1,0,0)$, $V=(u_1,u_2,u_3,0)$, $W=(u_1,u_2,u_3\cos\theta,u_3\sin\theta)$. Then $A\cdot V=A\cdot W=u_1$, $C\cdot  V=C\cdot W=u_2$, $V^2=W^2=u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2$, and $A\cdot C=0$, but $V\cdot W=u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3\cos \theta$ need not be zero.

@Letac 1. Lire plus attentivement l'énoncer... ; 2-3: il faut justement regarder la différence de comportement selon les directions, en écrivant par exemple explicitement les produits scalaires en fonction des angles. Il s'avère que l'intégrand ne se comporte pas en 1/r, mais diverge pour un rayon précis.
4: Ah, ça c'est intéressant !!!

Also, I take the point about $1/r$-divergence to be referring to the original integral prior to the Feynman parametrization. Once the latter is introduced, the singularity is now parametrized by the auxiliary variables $x_1,x_2$.

Ok, ok, I was wrong at 23 o'clock about the orthogonality of $V+W$ with respect  to $A$ and $C$.
